# Woocommerce hide product description on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to hide the product description in the product page. But when the user clicks on the description tab I need to show the content. When the user clicks again, I need to hide the description. It needs to work like toogle.

But I can not complete this. Please help. For to hide description on page load I place the following script on single-product.php

```
$('.wc-tab').hide();
```

It is working. When page load it is hidden and user clicks it is show (`description_tab active`)  automatically.

But I need to show hide every click. Please help

This is HTML structure

```
<ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
                            <li class="description_tab active">
                    <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery toggle function when you click the object that should show/hide the description.

The toggle function will show the element if it is currently hidden, or hide the element if it is currently shown.

```js
$(".wc-tabs").hide(); //start by hiding element
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".wc-tabs").toggle(); //toggle between hidden/shown when you click the button
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me!</button>
<ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
                            <li class="description_tab active">
                    <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Really thank you for the code . But could you please check this with given html structure . And there is no <button>Click Me!</button> or <button> . I can not alter the html structure also .

Comment: Which element should the user click to toggle the `.wc-tabs`?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the tab content on page load using Jquery and then you can show it when you click on tab title using Jquery.

// Remove Empty Tabs
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'yikes_woo_remove_empty_tabs', 20, 1 );

***Here’s a function that will remove any empty tabs:***

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'rf_woo_remove_empty_tabs', 20, 1 );
    function rf_woo_remove_empty_tabs( $tabs ) {

        if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) {
            foreach ( $tabs as $title => $tab ) {
                if ( empty( $tab['content'] ) ) {
                    unset( $tabs[ $title ] );
                }
            }
        }
        return $tabs;
    }
```

If you want to remove specific tabs, use the below function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'rf_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function rf_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove the description tab
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );          // Remove the reviews tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab

    return $tabs;

}
```